# Alias associated with the ip address

Tags: iis-7, ip, alias, windows-server-2008

An alias is associated with the ip address of my website, e.g.

```
ip address of my site = 10.75.XXX.XXX 
alias = mywebsitehosting.com
```

The S.O. is Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7

If getting on the browser:

> http://10.75.XXX.XXX/aspnet/

the server recognize correctly my user page identity

Instead if getting on the browser:

> http://mywebsitehosting.com/aspnet/

the server recognize me as administrator...

It's really strange because this problem only occurs with my account

All other accounts are properly recognized

The user page identity from AUTH_USER and this is the return of webpage

```
AUTH_USER: NameOfServer\Administrator
LOGON_USER: NameOfServer\Administrator
REMOTE_USER: NameOfServer\Administrator
```

The server is part of a corporate intranet and I think register the alias on Local AD DNS

I did not perform the association alias ip address...

These are application pool identity

```
ASP.NET v4.0 > Integrated
ASP.NET v4.0 Classic > Classic
Classic .NET AppPool  > Integrated
DefaultAppPool  > Integrated
DataTablesAppPool > Integrated (for NET CORE Application MVC)
```

and authentication

```
anonymous authentication enabled
basic authentication enabled
windows authentication enabled
all other authentication disabled
```

what is the problem ?

Depends on what?

[image]

Comment: You can try to use only Windows authentication and then clear the browser cache.

Comment: @samwu thanks I have tried to disable anonymous auth and basic auth, then clean browser cache and then iis reset without success.I don't understand. Why only for my account?

Comment: @samwu please see the image in tue question

Comment: Please check if the browser automatically fills in your username and password when you run as administrator.

Comment: @samwu on the browser the credential not are required. But is it possible because I am administrator of the machine from which I launch the browser to connect to the website? I have tried IE and Chrome and the problem it's the same...